# ReactBootstrap does not render tabs properly with React children

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, children, react-props

When I try to crate a ReactBootstrap Tabs nav (https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/), the actual clickable tabs do not render. I think this is because of how using this.props.children workflow works. I am using a JSON object to build my DOM:

```
 {
            "type": "FRAMEWORK_REGION_DASHBOARDS",
            "component": "FrameworkRegionDashboards",
            "className": "framework-region region-dashboards react-tab-panel",
            "order": 2,
            "style": {
              "ux": {
                "minHeight": "400px"
              },
              "dnd": {
                "minHeight": "502px",
                "padding": "10px",
                "backgroundColor": "rgb(220, 220, 220)"  
              }
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "type": "DASHBOARD_TAB_OVERVIEW",
                "component": "FrameworkDashboardTab",
                "className": "tab-pane",
                "order": 0,
                "title": "Overview",
                "visible": true,
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "Device Info",
                    "type": "PANEL_DASHBOARD_DEVICE_INFO",
                    "component": "PanelDashboardDeviceInfo",
                    "order": 0,
                    "size": {
                      "h": 1,
                      "v": 1
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
```

And I create the DashboardTabs like this:

```
        return React.createElement(
          ReactBootstrap.Tabs,
          {
            defaultActiveKey: 0,
            "id":        this.props.component.type,
            "name":      this.props.component.component,
            "className": this.props.component.className,
            "style":     this.props.component.style[this.props.dnd],
            "component": this.props.component 
          },
          this.props.children
        )
```

and then render the individual tabs like this

```
        return React.createElement(
          ReactBootstrap.Tab, 
          {
            "id": this.props.component.type,
            "name": this.props.component.title,
            "title": this.props.component.title,  
            "eventKey": this.props.component.order
          },
          this.props.children
        );
```

However what happens is that while the structure of the tabs DOM elements is added to the DOM, the  that should contain the actual clickable tabs, and the title, is empty

So instead of this

[image: How it should look]

I get this:

[image: How it actually looks]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just a general advice: Work with JSX, will be much easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: @i.brod unfortunately do to the limitations of our build process (legacy software), we cannot use JSX or React 16+